# How to get the view that is currently being displayed as an NSString?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, uiview, nsstring

I need to get the name of the view the user is currently viewing as an NSString, in order to save it so that I can return the user to this view if they exit my app. As of now, if a user exits my app on "View4" for instance my app will return them to "View1" if they launch it even immediately afterwards.
P.S. I know this is possible because many apps, such as tap tap revenge and angry birds do this. You can quit at any time and return, and the view and everything you were at will be saved.

Comment: Is your app multi tasking enabled? Normally there is nothing to do if "immediately afterwards" really means immediately afterwards.

Comment: Well, I mean if the user hits the home button and then as soon as the app closes they open my app again it starts all over from the beginning. So I need to save what they were looking at before they exited, so they aren't starting at View1 every sing time they open the app.

Comment: as I said, if the device is running iOS4 or later, and is capable of fast app switching (aka multitasking) this should happen automatically. iOS "freezes" the state of the app for you. Since you can see the behaviour in angry birds you should have an os version and a device capable of fast app switching (my ipod touch 2g starts angry birds from the beginning each time, same for tap tap revenge 2). So you should check your info.plist that you haven't enabled `Application does not run in background` (`UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend`)

Comment: Hm. Dang. I'm using an older version of XCode, but my iPod is running iOS4. So, is disabling that in the plist the only way to ensure the same view is recovered?

Answer (score 1):

Save the view name using [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  Then, when you app launches, try to retrieve the name from user defaults.

Comment: Right, that's what I as thinking. But how do I save the name of the view they are looking at? Or even, how do I know what view they are looking at?

Comment: I'm sure you figured out an answer to this a long time ago, but using NSUserDefaults this could be achieved quite simply by writing some strings to a plist, for example

firstView writes "1" to string
secondView writes "2" to string

then in applicationDidFinishLaunching

if string = 1 then firstView ETC... of course this is just one way of doing this.